Why does the radius come in the inner integral when integrating with polar coordinates?
Say I have the surface defined by $z = 9 - x^2-y^2$ and I want to calculate the volume between the $xy$ plane and this surface. The typical argument is that because $dA = rdrd\theta$, the volume is simply the following:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3(9-r^2)r\;dr\;d\theta$$
If you do the computation, you get a value of $\frac{81\pi}{2}$. However, when I try to make the argument in a different way, I get a different answer. I wanted to know the flaw in my line of reasoning.
Say you have fixed $\theta$ for some value within $[0,2\pi]$. We get some curve on the surface for this value of $\theta$.

This curve can then be plotted with respect to $r$.

At $r = 3, z = 0$. So, the area under this curve will just be:
$$\int_0^39-r^2\;dr$$
This integral comes out to be $18$. So, the area of one slice is $18$ units$^2$. Now, say you change the angle by a small $\Delta\theta$. As you rotate the slice by this angle, you sweep a "thickness" of $r\Delta\theta$ where $r$ is the length of the slice (which is just 3). So, you can say that the volume under the paraboloid will simply be:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}18(3)\;d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}54\;d\theta = 108\pi$$
When working with rectangular regions, you can think of fixing $x$ and then finding the area of the curve for some interval in $y$. Using this similar scheme in polar coordinates, however, does not seem to work since the answers obtained are different. Instead the variable $r$ must be taken in the inner integral. Why? Wherein lies the flaw in my argument?

The thickness of the slab is only $3\Delta\theta$ at the outer edge of the wedge. It's $0$ at $x=y=0$ and the thickness is $(3/2)\Delta\theta$ halfway out, etc. Using the variable $r\Delta\theta$ appropriately accounts for this.

I see. But wouldn't this mean that my incorrect approach would produce an underestimate? Why then is it greater than $\frac{81\pi}{2}?$

@Aryaan You assumed it was thick over the whole length, like a flat slab. But it is a smaller wedge instead (thinner near the origin than you'd assumed), so we would expect your approach to be an overestimate.

The simplest way to compute the volume, is by recognizing that a horizontal slab has surface area $S = \pi r^2$ and thickness $dz$. Hence the volume is given by:
$$V = \int _{0}^{9}\space \pi r^2 \space dz = \int _{0}^{9}\space \pi (9-z) \space dz = \space \frac {81}{2} \pi$$
It is also possible to regard the volume as a series of concentric cylinders with surface area $S = 2 \pi rz$ and thickness $dr$, as proposed by the OP. The volume is then given by:
$$V = \int _{0}^{3}\space 2\pi rz\space dr = \int _{0}^{3}\space 2\pi r(9-r^2) = \frac {81}{2} \pi$$
The second method proposed by the OP is incorrect, as explained by Mark S.

While this is a simple approach, it doesn't seem to address the question at the end of the post about where the flaw lies in the OP's approach.

That is correct. But the explanation you gave is fine.
